# Como utilizar Stream do Java 8 em uma lista de Object[]

Tags: java, lista, java-8, stream, collection

Imaginem o seguinte cenário: Uma lista de `Object[]`. Algo semelhante a isso:

```
    List<Object[]> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    Object[] dados = new Object[3];
    dados[0] = 1;
    dados[1] = 20;
    dados[1] = "cristiano";
    lista.add(dados);

    dados = new Object[3]; 
    dados[0] = 2;
    dados[1] = 40;
    dados[1] = "fulano";
    lista.add(dados);
```

Como eu faria para retornar uma lista de inteiros, contendo apenas o valores da primeira posição do array, utilizando o `Stream` do java 8?

O resultado esperado seria o seguinte:

```
1
2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use isso:

```
List<Integer> lista2 = lista.stream()
        .map(x -> (Integer) x[0])
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(lista2);
```

Saída:

```
[1, 2]
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/LjQdbf)

Comment: Cara, isso mesmo. Muito obrigado!

Comment: @CristianoBombazar  Se não lhe resta mais nenhuma dúvida acerca desta pergunta, clique no ✅ que aparece abaixo do número de votação desta resposta (ou da outra se você assim preferir) para marcá-la como aceita e marcar a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda tiver alguma dúvida, sinta-se livre para comentar. Foi um prazer ajudá-lo. 